# How to add headline that occupies entire width of dialog in angular material

Tags: html, angular, css, angular-material2

I am newbie in using Angular material. I wanted to have a headline  that occupies entire width in modal dialog. Is there any property provided by angular material where i can achieve the below functionality.

**what i would like to have**

[image]

**What i got**

[image]

**Here is the stackblitz link**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/matdialog-directives-demo-nl9bkr?file=app%2Ffile-name-dialog.component.ts

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have found the solution.I changed the mat-toolbar to h4 and did the custom styling.Here is the updated stackblitz link where you can find the solution.

**Here is the template file**

```
<h4 color="primary" class="dialog-headline">AddFile</h4>
    <mat-dialog-content>
      Content goes here
    </mat-dialog-content>
    <mat-dialog-actions>
      <button mat-button>Add</button>
      <button mat-button>Cancel</button>
    </mat-dialog-actions>
```

Here is the custom css

```
.dialog-headline{
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-top: -1em;
  margin-left: -1em;
  margin-right: -1em;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color:white;
}
```

**Result**

[image]

**You can find the live demo in the below link**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/matdialog-directives-demo-nl9bkr?file=app%2Ffile-name-dialog.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

You have to target the element mat-dialog-container element that is part of the dialog and remove its padding.

Something like that:

```css
mat-dialog-container.mat-dialog-container {
  padding:0;
}
```

Notice that I used to a tag selector plus a class selector to make the specifity of the selector higher.

Comment: side note, you need to add this code to a component with ViewEncapsulation set to none. "encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None"

Comment: Its not working. its affecting the remaining html.
Here is the update stackblitz link
https://stackblitz.com/edit/matdialog-directives-demo-nl9bkr?file=app%2Ffile-name-dialog.component.ts

Comment: Sorry I make a mistake in my first response. Its mat-dialog-container instead of mat-container-dialog.

Also if you want to use the CSS as is, you should set ViewEncapsulation to None or add the CSS to your global css file.